# When file_put_contents fails if the directory is full, a file with size 0 is created. How to avoid that?

Tags: php, temporary-files

When the tmp directory is full, file_put_contents returns FALSE but the file is created with size of 0. file_put_contents should either complete the creation of the file or have no effect at all. For example:

```
$data = 'somedata';
$temp_name = '/tmp/myfile';
if (file_put_contents($temp_name, $data) === FALSE) {
    // the message print that the file could not be created.
    print 'The file could not be created.';
}
```

But when I go to the tmp directory, I can find the file "myfile" created in the directory with size 0. This makes it difficult to maintain. The file should not be created and I would like to see a message or warning the the tmp directory is full. Am I missing anything? And is this normal behaviors?

Comment: Not how it works.  You can obviously detect the failure.  Maybe just delete the file and throw a warning?

Comment: The idea is file_put_contents is not atomic. Either finish the job or have not effect.

Comment: I am understanding more now where you are coming from.  Does the write mode (flags) factor in at all or does this happen in all modes?  I think [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) might be relevant: "This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file."

Comment: I filed a bug with with on the php website. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63908

Answer (score 4):

You are probably missing that if you do the error messages, you need to take care of that scenario, too:

```
$data      = 'somedata';
$temp_name = '/tmp/myfile';

$success = file_put_contents($temp_name, $data);
if ($success === FALSE)
{
    $exists  = is_file($temp_name);
    if ($exists === FALSE) {
        print 'The file could not be created.';
    } else {
        print 'The file was created but '.
              'it could not be written to it without an error.';
    }
}
```

This will also allow you to deal with it, like cleaning up if the transaction to write to the temporary file failed, to reset the system back into the state like before.

Comment: You should not compare `$success` to `FALSE` because `This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: @vojtek: See the three equal signs that do not only evaluate but also compare the exact type?

Comment: The idea is if file_put_contents fails, the file should not exist. I can myself do it, by checking if it exists and then deleting it using unlink. But, then again, the problem here is that the file_put_contents transaction is not atomic, either completely occur, or have no effects.

Comment: @ALI: `file_put_contents` does many things. It just does not clean up afterwards it looks like in case some error occurs. Yes, probably this is a flaw in PHP. You might even want to report this as a bug. If you do, please leave some reference here. http://bugs.php.net/

Comment: @hakre I filed a bug report with on the php site. This is what they had to say https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63908

Comment: @Ali: Report looks fine, thank you for reporting this. Rasmus alreay answered you and I'd say it's okay how he argues. The issue is now documented, so this should be now more clear. Also talk to your system administrator, the platter should never run against 0 for /temp unnoticed, take a look what your system is doing there.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that file_put_contents will not necessarily return a boolean value and therefore your condition may not be appropriate you could try:

```
if(!file_put_contents($temp_name, $data)){
    print 'The file could not be created.';
    if(file_exists ($temp_name))
        unlink($temp_name);
}
```

Comment: Not really describing the problem but same solution suppose.

Answer (score -1):

hi bro i found the Solution,

i know its old but its maybe help other people like me,

i was search about this code long time.

```
$data      = 'somedata';
$temp_name = '/tmp/myfile';

$success = file_put_contents($temp_name, $data);
  if (!$success){
     $exists  = is_file($temp_name);
     if (!$exists) {
        print 'The file could not be created.';
     } else {
       print 'The file was created but '.
       'it could not be written to it without an error.';
     }
  }
```

Comment: and its worked good, after use code @hakre and change FALSE to !